# Sobolev space of maps with higher dimensional target?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

Consider the space $W^{2,2}(\Omega)$ where $\Omega = [0,1]^3$.

This space contains continuous functions of the form $f:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$.

I am curious, can a Sobolev space be constructed by maps of the form
$ f:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}^3 $ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course. In general, $W^{k,p}(\Omega;\mathbb R^n)$ is the space of (equivalence classes of) functions $f\colon\Omega\to\mathbb R^n$ such that $D^\alpha f_j\in L^p(\Omega)$ for all multi-indices $\alpha$ with $|\alpha|\leq k$ and $j\in\{1,\dots,n\}$. This means that $f\colon \Omega\to\mathbb R^n$ belongs to $W^{k,p}(\Omega;\mathbb R^n)$ if and only if all the coordinate functions $f_1,\dots,f_n$ belong to the scalar-valued Sobolev space $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you also give the standard definition of the inner product in such spaces ?

Comment: If we embrace the identification of $W^{k,2}(\Omega;\mathbb R^n)$ with $W^{k,2}(\Omega)^n$, then this is pretty straightforward: $\langle f,g\rangle_{W^{k,2}(\Omega;\mathbb R^n)}=\sum_{j=1}^n \langle f_j,g_j\rangle_{W^{k,2}(\Omega)}$.